# PHP: get an array of specific tag content

Tags: php, html

I have an html string like this one (this is not the entirely html):

```
<h2>Title A</h2>
  <p>aaaaaa</p>
  <p>bbbbbb</p>
<h2>Title B</h2>
  <p>aaaaaa</p>
  <p>bbbbbb</p>
<h2>Title C</h2>
  <p>aaaaaa</p>
  <p>bbbbbb</p>
```

And I would like to get an array with only titles (from h2 tag):

```
array(Title A, title B, Title C);
```

I am using php.

I have tried

```
strip_tags(string,'<h2>')
```

but I am getting the title followed by the content after the `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try using `DOMDocument`

```
    $html = '<h2>Title A</h2>
      <p>aaaaaa</p>
      <p>bbbbbb</p>
    <h2>Title B</h2>
      <p>aaaaaa</p>
      <p>bbbbbb</p>
    <h2>Title C</h2>
      <p>aaaaaa</p>
      <p>bbbbbb</p>';

$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');

for($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i ++) {
    echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
Title A
Title B
Title C
```

Comment: @sics nice .. but that only worked because of the enclosed `HTML` tag .. +1

Comment: Thank you very much @Baba, I am using this in symfony2 and I am getting an error like DOMDocument' not found...

Comment: @Baba, I am using 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) but I ma trying to execute the code in a symfony controller.

Comment: In Command Line Interface .. Just type `yum install php-xml` then `service httpd restart`

Comment: I doubt that symfony works w/o DomDocument, so keep namespaces into account when you write your code, I updated my answer.

Comment: @baba: user is using ubuntu, there is no yum. However the suggestion is right, let them check if the package is installed.

Comment: @hakra i totally agree ..... +1 for the namespace tip ... have also updated my code for namespace issues

Comment: @Baba, on trying yum install php-xml i am getting No package php-xml available.
Nothing to do

Comment: @Baba i have DOM/XML  enabled

Comment: ok try replacing `new DOMDocument();` with `new \DOMDocument();` .. it might be a namespace issue as hakra suggested

Comment: @Milos you are welcome :D .. thanks to hakra for the namespace

Answer (score 3):

PHP has good libraries for HTML parsing already build in, here a parser with xpath:

```
$h2 = array_map(
    'strval', simplexml_import_dom(\DomDocument::loadHTML($html))->xpath('//h2')
);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Title A"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Title B"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Title C"
}
```

See as well the other DOMDocument related answer, if you hear HTML and PHP just think DomDocument.

---

```
$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$h2  = array_map(
    'strval', simplexml_import_dom($doc)->xpath('//h2')
);
```

Comment: Impressive Code in just 3 lines

Comment: You get strict standard warnings however because of calling `loadHTML` statically, just saying.

Comment: +1 its like you are reading my mind ..... How can you modify the code to remove that error ???

Comment: @Baba: see the edit, I just make use of simplexml here to get easy access to xpath.

Comment: @hakra guessed as much ... was thinking you would come up with another crazy one line code .... :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a parser such as [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php) to parse the HTML.

Comment: Thank you @Wayne, there is no php method to do this easier?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of DOMDocument you can use SimpleXML

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Esairr

```
$html = '
    <html>
        <h2>Title A</h2>
        <p>aaaaaa</p>
        <p>bbbbbb</p>
        <h2>Title B</h2>
        <p>aaaaaa</p>
        <p>bbbbbb</p>
        <h2>Title C</h2>
        <p>aaaaaa</p>
        <p>bbbbbb</p>
    </html>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml->h2);
echo "</pre>";
```

output

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => Title A
    [1] => Title B
    [2] => Title C
)
```

Comment: Problem with this is that simplexml has problems to load HTML. DomDocument can load HTML better. That is why I have combined

Comment: yes, @hakra 's solution is better. nevertheless if you tend to use this approach be aware that you can only pass "well formed" html into the constructor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element

Answer (score 0):

you could use `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all("/<h2>(.*?)</h2>/si", $sResource, $aTitles);
print_r($aTitles[1]);
```

It is discouraged to parse HTML with PHP like this though, because of specific chars, newlines etc. that can intefere with your script. DOM Parser will be a good and easy alternative for this.

Comment: Please give me the reason why -1. I just give the OP an option, but I did add that regex is discouraged and DOM Parser is a better option.

Comment: But you've still used regex to parse html. BTW, I am not downvoter.

Comment: @PLB everybody has been a noob before, and yes, I have done it this way before. It does work if you use the right wildcards the right way, and when the page is static it won't be a problem anytime soon. Like I said, I'm just giving him an option.